# What needs to be added in code to remove spaces in config file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, configparser

i have a config file and when i write into it it has spaces in it

Answer (score 4):

Here is the definition of `RawConfigParser.write`:

```
def write(self, fp):
    """Write an .ini-format representation of the configuration state."""
    if self._defaults:
        fp.write("[%s]\n" % DEFAULTSECT)
        for (key, value) in self._defaults.items():
            fp.write("%s = %s\n" % (key, str(value).replace('\n', '\n\t')))
        fp.write("\n")
    for section in self._sections:
        fp.write("[%s]\n" % section)
        for (key, value) in self._sections[section].items():
            if key != "__name__":
                fp.write("%s = %s\n" %
                         (key, str(value).replace('\n', '\n\t')))
        fp.write("\n")
```

As you can see, the `%s = %s\n` format is hard-coded into the function.  I think your options are:

1. Use the INI file with whitespace around the equals
2. Overwrite `RawConfigParser`'s `write` method with your own
3. Write the file, read the file, remove the whitespace, and write it again

If you're 100% sure option 1 is unavailable, here's a way to do option 3:

```
def remove_whitespace_from_assignments():
    separator = "="
    config_path = "config.ini"
    lines = file(config_path).readlines()
    fp = open(config_path, "w")
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line.startswith("#") and separator in line:
            assignment = line.split(separator, 1)
            assignment = map(str.strip, assignment)
            fp.write("%s%s%s\n" % (assignment[0], separator, assignment[1]))
        else:
            fp.write(line + "\n")
```